# What is this error, I do not understand

Tags: android

```
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewGroupCompat.getLayoutMode
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Bounds.include(GridLayout.java:2155)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.computeGroupBounds(GridLayout.java:1203)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getGroupBounds(GridLayout.java:1212)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.createLinks(GridLayout.java:1221)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getForwardLinks(GridLayout.java:1247)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.createArcs(GridLayout.java:1372)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getArcs(GridLayout.java:1405)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.computeLocations(GridLayout.java:1576)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getLocations(GridLayout.java:1597)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getMeasure(GridLayout.java:1618)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getMeasure(GridLayout.java:1626)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.onMeasure(GridLayout.java:957)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1279)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at  android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:361)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1274)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:354)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:845)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-06 15:28:51.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3270):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Without context, all I can say is that there is no such method.

Comment: Before you post here, you should try doing a web search on a quoted section of the error message. (like "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError").  You should then post not just the code, but what you were doing, and anything you might have found from the search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the correct(latest) version of the v4 support library. I've had the same error until I realized that I was using older v4 support library ( which lacks this API 18 method ).

Answer (score 4):

That means that you are calling the method getLayoutMode in a device below API 18 and that method was only added in API 18 as you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getLayoutMode%28%29).

Comment: Agreed, make sure to check your manifest. Without further context, we cannot see where this originates from other than something in the main UI thread in the main activity possibly.